# Phrases about changing schools

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning, idioms

I want to talk about changing schools someday and I want to ask which phrase is the commonest.

- change schools
- transfer to another school
- go to another school
- move to another school

If anything else is common, I'm glad to hear it.

I will use it when I'm talking to my friend. What is the proper use when you say like "by the way, maybe I'm gonna go to another school."

Comment: Welcome to ELL! All four expressions are idiomatic. None is more common than any other. To better understand what we do and how we do it, please review our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. They will help you ask a better question.

Comment: When a student changes a school, he/she has to get TC (Transfer Certificate); and this supports your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - change schools

This is a common phrase and can be used conversationally.

> - transfer to another school

This is slightly more formal, and might be a better term to use when communicating with the registrar's offices of the two institutions.

> - go to another school

This phrase will work – there is nothing wrong about it – but it could mean something more temporary and less permanent (such as a one-semester exchange study abroad).

> - move to another school

This phrase could work, too, but I probably wouldn't use it unless I was moving to another city. (I probably wouldn't say this if I was going to start going to a different school in the same city as my first.)

In short, in informal conversations, like the one you mention in your question, any of these will work:

> *By the way, maybe I'm gonna go to another school*.
>   *By the way, maybe I'm gonna transfer to Sanders University*.
>   *By the way, I'm thinking about changing schools. I'll be attending Sanders in the fall*.

And, if Sanders University is not located where you live now:

> *By the way, I think I'll be moving to Sanders next year*.

Answer (score 0):

In your examples

> **change** schools
>   **go to another** school
>   **move to another** school

are all non specific indicating a change of schooling. "**Move** to another school" may imply you are moving your *residence*, because of the word "**move**" which "**change**" and "**go to another**" do not.

However

> **transfer** to another school

is more specific and implies that credits you have already earned toward a degree will be *transferred* to the new institution so you will not need to retake requisite courses over again.

When you "**transfer** to another school", you are doing any one of the first three.

All four statements are commonly used interchangeably.